# Animator Component gets removed automatically - Unity

Tags: unity, animation

I am creating a simple scaling animation on image (in Unity). When I play game in unity editor, the animator component get removed automatically. Here I am copying snapshop of Inspector of Image.

[image]

What should I correct?

Comment: are you sure the animator component is getting removed or the  image is just not showing up during the scaling animation. Unity had a bug with scaling UI elements with animation. If you are sure that the component itself is getting removed during the  animation then most probably the action was recorded in the animation. Check the key frames.

Comment: Scaling action is being recorded, animator component is added to the control with correct controller, but after play the component gets removed itself. And I manually need to add animator component.

Comment: God this is a strange problem. Are you sure you are not adding when you are already in PLAY mode. I've never heard of components randomly disappearing.

Comment: obviously, I am sure. Confirmed it by creating animation and playing a game 100 times. But I've temporarily solved it by manually adding a component.